# Using Next Js to send the request instead of client side transitions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, next.js

Started understanding Next js and trying to use along with React, while Next js addresses the SEO friendly topics such as SSR, default code-splitting, using pages directory it also forces to use `<Link>` components instead of `<a>`enabling the default client side transitions after the very first request, How can i send the request to server everytime ? Is there a way we can avoid client-side transitions and enable the browser default behavior.

Thanks in Advance

```
const Check = () => {

   return (<Link href="/about"> <a> About </a> </Link>);
}
```

Using Link is mandatory and it disables the browser default loading ensuring the client transitions, How can we enable the browser default without client side transitions. I have seen the .eslint json specific config in their documentation and unable to find any property for that.

**EDIT:**

[image: When is used]

Comment: You can simply not use the `next/link` component if you don't want client-side navigations handled by Next.js (use regular `<a>` elements). Out of curiosity, why would you want the request to go to the server every time? This may reduce your site's performance considerably.

Comment: @juliomalves, Thanks for the comment, please check the edit when <a> alone is used, To answer your question, we are trying to use things like adsense in the app which is not flexible with SPA applications and although google claims it can index SPA apps well and adsense too works well,There is no enough proof(prerender.io service is an example for that) and the script is claimed to be asynchronous but the adds won't appear when we use client side transitions.  it  only appears when it is refreshed or reloaded...

Comment: You can disable that specific lint rule in your `.eslintrc` file to avoid the build error, i.e. `"rules": { "@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages": "off" }`.